# session en JSP con el Retroceso del navegador

Tags: jsp

tengo un problema en la seguridad del código, lo he simplificado para que quede más claro:

```
<form name="formconf" action="hola.jsp" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="txtname" value="">
   <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="idbtnsend" name="btnsend" >
 </form>


hola.jsp

<%
    String saludo = request.getParameter("txtname");
    session.setAtribute("login",request.getParameter("txtname"));


%>
   <h1>Hola<%=saludo %></h1>
   <a href="chat.jsp">continuar</a>


chat.jsp

<%
   if(session.getAtribute("login")!=null){
    out.println("Entro porque existe");
   }else{
       out.println("No estás logueado");
    }

%>
    <a href="desconectarse.jsp">Desconectarse</a>


desconectarse.jsp
<%
    session.setAtribute("login",null);

    [
        responsive.setredirect(index.jsp);
    ]
    [
        <a href="index.jsp">volver al index</a>
    ]

%>
```

Entonces cuando le da a desconectarse pone la variable login a null.
Cuando intenta acceder a chat.jsp por la barra de navegador lo hace bien porque vale null. PERO si le da hacia atrás con las flechas del navegador PUEDE ACCEDER y no debería porque está a null... qué hago ??

Comment: Define "puede acceder". Si le das para atrás, el navegador recarga la página desde la caché, pero seguramente cualquier intento de navegar desde ahí falle puesto que la sesión se ha borrado en el servidor.

Comment: Mientras el usuario está en el programa tiene una variable session para acceder al contenido, cuando le da a desconectar, PONGO esa variable a null.
Si el usuario INTENTA acceder a las páginas poniendo la ruta desde el navegador, no puede acceder porque la variable está a null, Eso es lo que yo quiero.
EL PROBLEMA viene cuando el usuario, le da hacia atrás en las barras del navegador, porque SÍ puede acceder a pesar de que la variable session está a null....

Acceder es que ve el contenido de las páginas cuando ya le dió a desconectarse"

Comment: Entonces el problema es que en el lado de servidor no haces la comprobación correctamente o se recrea una nueva sesión cuando no debe

Comment: if(session.getAtribute("login")!=null){
    out.println("Entro porque existe");
   }else{
       out.println("No estás logueado");
    }

Ya dije que si intenta acceder desde la barra de navegación funciona, pero con las flechas para ir pa trás no.